# Prove: $ \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$, there exists a unique $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $n-1\leq x<n$.

Tags: real-analysis

For all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, there exists a unique $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $n-1\leq x<n$.

I know Archimedean Property gives $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x<m$, but what then can we say about $m-1$?

Comment: **Hint :** Take the smallest $m$ such that $x<m$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Why can we do that? (I'm rusty with RA)

Comment: Because every non-empty subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ that has a finite lower bound has a smallest element.

Comment: This ^ is a hop, skip, and jump away from the well-ordering of the natural numbers. It's a seemingly stronger statement, but it's actually just straight up equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Then by the Archimedean Property, there is some $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x<m$. Let $M$ be the set of all such $m$, then $M$ has a lower bound of $x$, and thus it must have a smallest element $n$. Since $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $n-1\in\mathbb{Z}$, and $n-1\leq x<n$.

(Should I add more detail to that last part?)